# change coin implementation issue

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I ran into an implementation problem when trying to solve this classic problem using DP. 
The problem is given a set of coins, and return the number of ways of making a change.

The DP equation is something like the following:
    DP[i] += DP[i - coin[j]]
where DP[i] means the number of ways of making change for i.

Here is a straightforward implementation, which is incorrect:

```
int make_change_wrong(int coin[], int size, int change) {
    vector<int> DP(change + 1, 0);
    DP[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= change; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (i - coin[j] >= 0 ) {
                DP[i] += DP[i - coin[j]];
            }
        }
    }

    return DP[change];
}
```

Given input:
int coin[] = {1, 5}
change = 6.

make_change_wrong(coin, 2, 6) returns 3, but 2 is correct.

Using the same logic, I re-write it in a less intuitive way and get the correct answer:

```
int make_change(int coin[], int size, int change) {
    vector<int> DP(change + 1, 0);
    DP[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = coin[i]; j <= change; ++j) {
            DP[j] += DP[j - coin[i]];
        }
    }

    return DP[change];
}
```

This puzzled me a lot because to me, they're the same thing...
Can someone illustrate a bit on the problems in the two implementations?

Comment: If you're getting a different answer between the two implementations, then clearly they are NOT equivalent.  Perhaps you can insert some debugging statements to print out the contents of the DP array as you are building it; this may help to illustrate how they are different.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I know the first function counts {1,1,1,1,1} twice, but I didn't see why the second counts correctly -- they seem to be coded only in two different ways.

Answer (score 4):

Your first algorithm is wrong.

DP[5] = 2 {1,1,1,1,1}, {5}

DP[6] = DP[5] + DP[1] = 3

you are counting {5,1} twice.
**EDITED**
So the standard trick for doing this is that you keep a count of the denomination you are allowed to use

```
DP[i,m] = DP[i-coin[m],m] + DP[i,m-1]
```

which means number of ways of making a change of i amount using coins in range[1..m].
This is obviously, you either use the mth denomination or you don't.

The second algorithm you are using is doing the same trick but is a really clever way to do that, take the ith coin and see what all change you can generate using it. This will avoid over counting because you avoid doing things like {1,5} and {5,1}.

Comment: Thanks sukunrt, I understand that my first function gets this input wrong and it counts {1,1,1,1,1} twice. I just can't see why coding using the same idea generates different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is in the interview prep book *Cracking the Coding Interview*, and the solution given in the book is not optimized at all.  It uses recursion (without DP) to calculate sub-problems repeatedly and therefore runs in O(N^3) which is especially ironic since it's part of the Dynamic Programming chapter.

Here's a very simple working solution (Java) which uses DP and runs in O(N) time.

```
static int numCombos(int n) {
    int[] dyn = new int[n + 1];
    Arrays.fill(dyn, 0);
    dyn[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1;  i <= n; i++) dyn[i] += dyn[i - 1];
    for (int i = 5;  i <= n; i++) dyn[i] += dyn[i - 5];
    for (int i = 10; i <= n; i++) dyn[i] += dyn[i - 10];
    for (int i = 25; i <= n; i++) dyn[i] += dyn[i - 25];
    return dyn[n];
}
```

Comment: Nice observation on the CCI book, The111! For many problems, I think the provided solutions are not quite "neat". You code is essential the same as my second attempt. One thing about DP is that even if we have successfully obtained the recursion equation, it's still tricky to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try your input for your second method:

```
coin[5] = {1,5,10,20,30};
make_change(coin,5,30);
```

It returns 21. Please check my test case.